# Connect to Google Calendar using Smack API in JAVA

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, smack

Can anyone tell me how to connect to Google Calendar server using the Smack API, if i can do that.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by connecting to Google Calendar using Smack? Smack will let you connect to an XMPP server, which is an instant messaging means. If you want something similar to http://clockwerx.blogspot.com/2008/10/interacting-with-google-calendar-via.html then there are two sides: implement the bot and then connect to it and talk to it.
But generally speaking, here's a code sample that will let you connect to GTalk:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.proxy.ProxyInfo;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence.Type;

public class Communicator {
    public static final String XMPP_SERVER = "talk.google.com";
    public static final String XMPP_HOST_NAME = "gmail.com";
    public static final String XMPP_SERVICE_NAME = "gmail.com";
    public static final int PACKET_REPLY_TIMEOUT = 500, DEFAULT_XMPP_SERVER_PORT = 5222;

    XMPPConnection conn;
    Roster buddyList;

    public static String canonicalizeUsername(String username) {
        if (!username.contains("@")) {
            username += "@" + XMPP_SERVICE_NAME;
        }
        return username;
    }

    public Communicator(String username, String password) throws XMPPException {
        this(XMPP_SERVER, DEFAULT_XMPP_SERVER_PORT, username, password);
    }

    public Communicator(String serverAddress, Integer serverPort, String username,
                        String password) throws XMPPException {
        username = canonicalizeUsername(username);
        SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(PACKET_REPLY_TIMEOUT);
        ConnectionConfiguration config =
                  new ConnectionConfiguration(serverAddress, serverPort != null ? serverPort : DEFAULT_XMPP_SERVER_PORT,
                                              XMPP_HOST_NAME, ProxyInfo.forDefaultProxy());
        //config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        //config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
        //SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
        conn = new XMPPConnection(config);
        conn.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected to " + serverAddress + ":" + serverPort);
        conn.login(username, password);
        System.out.println("Logged in as " + username);
        setStatus(true, "ON");
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean available, String status) {
        Presence presence = new Presence(available ? Type.available : Type.unavailable);
        presence.setStatus(status);
        conn.sendPacket(presence);
    }

    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        conn.disconnect();
    }

    public boolean sendMessage(String msgText, String to) throws XMPPException {
        to = canonicalizeUsername(to);
        ChatManager mgr = conn.getChatManager();
        Chat chat = mgr.createChat(to, new MessageListener() {
                public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message msg) {
                    System.out.println(msg.getBody());
                }
            });
        //important bit is to set Message type to 'chat', Google seems to ignore the default type
        Message msg = new Message(msgText, Message.Type.chat);
        chat.sendMessage(msg);
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Communicator comm = new Communicator("username", "password");
        comm.sendMessage("", "");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close this when you want to quit");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i have a google calender, that i need to access through JAVA API mainly. For that we have Google data API , but the thing is , that calender is publicly shared and if one of the guys want to see if any changes have been made to the calender by anyone , he should be able to get a notification on his own without doing polling.Kind of subscribing ,that i am unable to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the problem still persists after that long time. But for future users searching for an answer I will provide it.

Smack API is used for XMPP messaging. It is unlikely you get calendar access with that.

Most (cloud based) calendars do work based on a specialization of [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) which is called [CalDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV). A suitable client library is [caldav4j](https://github.com/caldav4j/caldav4j).